# Map property to property of a collection automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two entities

```
public class A{
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> BCollection { get;set; } = new HashSet<B>();
}

public class B {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple ViewModel

```
public class AFirstLoadViewModel {
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The thing, is, this viewmodel will be use only in the first data entry, when `A` will only have one `B` object inside.

So, i'm trying to map a object like this:

```
var source = new AFirstLoadViewModel
{
    Example = "example",
    MyProperty = "myproperty"
}
```

to this

```
var destination = new A {
    Example = "example"
    BCollection = new List<B> {
        new B { MyProperty = "myproperty" }
    }
}
```

I try to do the trick using `ForPath` and `BeforeMap` without luck

```
CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Example, c => c.MapFrom(x => x.Example))
    .ForPath(x => x.BCollection.First().MyProperty, c => c.MapFrom(x => x.MyProperty))
    .BeforeMap((viewModel, entity) => {
        if(!entity.BCollection.Any())
            BCollection.Add(new B());
    });
```

But i get

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Only member accesses are allowed.

How can i deal with it?

*I clarify: both, view model and model have many more properties, the question classes are by way of example*

Edit:

---

I try the solution proposed by Johnatan, and it works, the problem here, is that i cant Unit Testing anymore.

I'm testing with

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A>(MemberList.Source));
```

And when i call `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` fails because the `MyProperty` property is not mapped

Comment: Hi Juan,

That's because you are asserting a bad configuration.

You are asserting this...

cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A>

Which is not the map you've created.

CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A> is an invalid map, not the answer provided.

Comment: @Lee thanks, i didnt see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to map to .First(). First does not yet exist because the query is on a null / empty collection. You can't assign to the .First() element in a collection if one does not exist already. Instead just map as a collection directly.

```
CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A>()
.ForMember(x => x.Example, c => c.MapFrom(x => x.Example))
.ForMember(x => x.BCollection, c => c.MapFrom(x => new [] { new B { MyProperty = x.MyProperty } }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Its a good idea, but i'm having issues when i try to Unit Test with this approach, because `AssertConfigurationisValid` check if `MyProperty` is mapped, and it doesnt

Comment: @Johnathan you are right I just saw your answer above and amended it so they're identitcal really. However to the point of AssertConfigurationValid, I'd probably remove it from your tests. Just test the maps and Assert the results. Assert configuration fails often when your are doing something a little custom (such as this). Just ensure that your maps work in your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

```
CreateMap<AFirstLoadViewModel, A>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Example, c => c.MapFrom(x => x.Example))
    .ForMember(x => x.BCollection, c => c.MapFrom(x => new [] { new B { MyProperty = x.MyProperty } }));
```

Comment: Thanks for you anser!, thats a good idea, but my problem now, is that i cant use automapper unit testing with that method